# Cannot add days in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Could anyone  explain why this very simple piece of code does not work?

```
   var date=moment();
   var chosenDate = moment(date,"YYYY-MM-DD");  
   var chosenDay=chosenDate.format('dddd');  
   var day=chosenDate.add(2,'days');
   console.log( day.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

and instead of getting "2016-09-01", I am getting "2016-08-30". I am going to be mad...

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/wyumu146/).

Comment: Why do you create a moment from a moment with a wrong format???